# How to inherit an element type that is provided by a plugin?

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to inherit `GstTextOverlay`, but the farthest I can go is this link-time error "undefined reference to `gst_text_overlay_get_type'".

According to the Makefile, it is `lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstpango.so` that provides `GstTextOverlay`, but within the .so file there is no symbol `gst_text_overlay_get_type`. The only symbols that are exported by the .so file are `gst_plugin_pango_register` and `gst_plugin_pango_get_desc`.

So, how can I inherit the `GstTextOverlay` without calling `gst_text_overlay_get_type`? Or, is there a way to access `gst_text_overlay_get_type`? Thanks. :)

Comment: I guess you will need stuff from here: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/master/ext/pango and read the plgins writer guide: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/ . And instead of the inheriting from GstElement or one of the other common base classes to you will inherit from GstTextOverlay. The pango plugin itself only has a very basic entry point. That won't get you very far for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling : 
https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good
https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-base

If that will not help try reinstalling gstreamer
have a look [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2232109) this might help you as well.

Comment: Yes, I do have gst-plugins-base installed. Could you please be more specific? By the way, I already managed to compile my .c files successfully into .o files. The question I was asking is about a link-time error, not a compile-time error. So, .h files probably are not an issue.

Comment: What is the environment you are building in are you using gcc?? If yes what versions etc. system info as well

Comment: Could you paste your error output as well so I can have a look into it.